# Current way to get Home URL (Domain) in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

This is so simple, yet it seems that its not provided.

Basically, if my site is...

- http://www.example.com
- http://127.0.0.1:8000

Or a non-root install like

- http://www.example.com/ye-ol-django/
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/ye-ol-django/

...I would think django would know this and have a constant available in templates.

The solutions I find involve:

1. Set it up in settings.py with `SITE_URL =`
2. Reference settings.py in a view.
3. Finally access it in the template with **`{{ SITE_URL }}`** or something.

Not very **D.R.Y.**

*Not to sound spoiled, but doesn't django provide the `{{ GET_ME_THE_ROOT_URL }}` reference?*

Sorry, django has trained me to expect goodies like this.

Just sayin' if I was writing a framework that would be the first thing I do, besides putting a small fridge beside my desk full of hotpockets and a microwave a safe but close distance away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ha! Nice question.

Let's break down your problem. You want some data to be available across all the templates available in your project. And also, you want to provide the value once and not repeat it across views.

Template Context Processors is the thing you are looking for.
In your `settings.py` file, add a new context_processor to the list of `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "your_app.context_processors.root_url"
)
```

Then, inside `your_app`, create a file named `context_processors.py`. This file will contain the following code.

```
from django.conf import settings

def root_url(request):
    """
    Pass your root_url from the settings.py
    """
    return {'SITE_URL': settings.ROOT_URL_YOU_WANT_TO_MENTION}
```

And, in each of your templates, you'll have a `{{SITE_URL}}` present in the context depending on the value you provide to `ROOT_URL_YOU_WANT_TO_MENTION` in your `settings.py` file.

Django sure spoils everyone. But provides the mechanisms to keep you spoilt.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you're rendering the template from a request, you can just name your root view, then refer to it with the url tag:

In your root urls.py:

`url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),`

In template.html:

```
click <a href="{% url 'home' %}">here</a>
```

More good info over in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: I get that part, but if I have a stylesheet and I want to give a full url to it, how do I get access to that localhost or web base? Right now it starts with a '/' which can be tricky especially if it ends up being a non-root install.

Comment: Ohhhh man. I see what you mean. In urls.py, you should just name the base url: `url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')`, then call that with `{% url 'home' %}`. Updated answer to reflect that.